# Can I bind AppBarButtons into CommandBar.PrimaryCommands

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I want to bind an AppBarButtons into a CommandBar.

I tried looking through the CommandBar documentation and found out that part is `PrimaryCommands` but I try to bind it but it read-only and I can't write anything to it.

Here is what I wanted to do.

```xml
<CommandBar PrimaryCommands={x:Bind AdditionCommands}/>
```

So, later on, I could just:

```xml
<customUI:PauseMenu>
    <customUI:PauseMenu.AdditionCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="Some"/>
        <AppBarButton Label="Commands"/>
        <AppBarButton Label="Heres"/>
    </customUI:PauseMenu.AdditionCommands>
</customUI:PauseMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I bind AppBarButtons into CommandBar.PrimaryCommands

CommandBar does not support bind `PrimaryCommands` like the above. The only implementation way of `PrimaryCommands` is create list `AppBarButton` under that  node. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars).

```
<CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    <AppBarButton Label="Some"/>
    <AppBarButton Label="Commands"/>
    <AppBarButton Label="Heres"/>
</CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
```